# Как верстать такой фон?

Tags: html, css

Практикуюсь в верстке и хотел узнать, как верстаются такие элементы?

[image: фон секции]

Скачивать эту картинку как свг и позиционировать через абсолют, либо же как-то обрезать и прижимать к краю?

Comment: какую эту картинку?

Comment: которая идет белым на фоне, за самой картинкой

Answer (score 0):

Спросить у дизайнера как он это видит. Если важна производительность, то попросить, что б обрезали по ширине макета, и тогда, да - забрать вектор полубуквы и задать через `position:absolute; top:-80px; right:0; z-index:1;` Или же слепить все изображения в один png и не париться. Там надо от макета смотреть.